# How do you download a a jar file with java?

Tags: java, networking, download

I'm trying to implement an updates feature in my program. If an update is available, there will have to be one if not several different .jar files that must be downloaded. I'm having problems developing a way to download these files. I've looked at the URLConnection API as well as other API's related to this. I can download regular text files with no problem, but when I need to download a jar file it just doesn't download. No error is thrown, the data just isn't transferred.

If anyone can point me in the right direction to successfully download jar files I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If you want an app that updates itself, you may want to look at Java WebStart.

Comment: it would really help to post a small example of the code you are trying to use.

Comment: let me guess, you are using windows so the jar files are locked

Comment: @Thilo  Yes, [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) has already solved this problem (and many others related to deploying desktop apps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about JAR files themselves.  Transfer it just like any other file (FileInputStream -> SocketOutputStream: SocketInputStream->FileOutputStream).  The trick is to use the `ClassLoader` to link the classes into your running program after you have saved the JAR to disk.

Comment: but if the app is updating its own jars it will have to handle file locking in windows

Comment: put a version number or other distinguishing info into the file name to avoid this.  overwriting the live jars is a bad practice.

Comment: I know how I'm going to update, I just can't figure out how to download it. Can you point me to an example?